# how to get dropdown value and id selected in form in spring

Tags: spring, select, spring-mvc, drop-down-menu

I am using Spring MVC.
In my model I have a Map (say optionsMap) that will display dropdown options in UI. This is a multi selection dropdown. Id is an integer and display value is a string. On submit of form, controller should be able to get id(s) and value(s) of the selected options into a map (selectedOptionsMap).

```
    <form:select path="selectedOptionsMap" id="deviceList" multiple="true"></form:select>
```

Answer (score 0):

This has already been discussed at [Multiple Select in Spring 3.0 MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331532/multiple-select-in-spring-3-0-mvc) . Check it out. You will need a custom editor here .