# Spring select multiple tag and binding

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to use the select tag of spring to select multiple options to fill a List.
My select tags is well displayed and when I select options the List is correctly updated.

The only problem I have is when I render the for with an already filled List, my select tag does not highlight the selected options. I have try to debug and Ican see that the List is not empty, it is really the tag that seems to not mark the selected options as selected.

My code :

```
@Entity
public class ProductsGroup
{
    @Version  @Column(name = "version")
    private Integer version;
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Product> products; 

    public List<Product> getProducts()
    {
        return products;
    }

    public void setProducts(List<Product> products)
    {
        this.products = products;
    }
}

@Entity
public class Product
{
    @Version @Column(name = "version")
    private Integer version;

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

<form:form action="${action}" class="fancyform" commandName="productsGroup" id="productForm">
    ....
    <form:select path="products" items="${products}" itemLabel="name" itemValue="id" multiple="true"/>
    ....
</form:form>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's probably due to the fact that the list of selected products doesn't contain the same instances as the complete list of displayed products.

The tag compares products with `equals()`, and you have not overridden `equals()` (and `hashCode()`) in your Product class.

So even if the selected products contain the Product with the name "foo", and the complete list of Product also contains a Product with the name "foo", those products are not equal, and Spring thus doesn't know they're the same product, and that this product should thus be selected.

Comment: Awesome! I was thinking that it was using the itemValue to compare! Indeed, using equals makes more sense...