# What type is used for a Select:multiple in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I want to add a Select:multiple tag to my JSP and then map it to a form model class, where I'll retrieve the data loaded.

But I did not find what type to use for the variable so that I can do it.

What would it be?

Ex.:
JSP

```
<form:select multiple="true" path="harmonic">
    <c:forEach begin='1' end='15' varStatus='loop'>
    <form:options items="<--Variable?->" itemValue="loop" itemLabel="loop"/>
    </c:forEach>
<form:select>
```

Class

```
public class HarmonicForm{

    private ???? selectMultiple;

}
```

Comment: did you try with an array of ids?

Comment: Nope. Could an array work?

Comment: I think could also work, but with a list is easier to handle it, so better go for the list approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring selects admit any Collection like List or Set.

```
private List<YOUR_OBJECT_TYPE_HERE> selectMultiple;
```

You can pass your model to the view and there's no need to use foreach nor option tag.

```
<form:select multiple="true" path="harmonic" items="${items}" itemLabel="harmonicLabelAttribute" itemValue="harmonicValueAttribute" />
```

You can check the TLD documentation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-form-tld.html#spring-form.tld.select).

Comment: Ok, so a question: if I add the ${items} to the select, how to define that ${items} collection and how could I know which was selected? In my case I want the user to select from 1-15, any and each number he wants.

Comment: ${items} are set using model.put(itemsCollection) from your controller. Once the form is submitted the object selectMultiple should be initializased with the selected objects. Spring will do it's magic so you don't have to worry about that.

Comment: So I could also add a variable to the form model where I have a list with all the objects I want to be available in the select? This way I can controll the numbers from the model.

Comment: That's right. You can have an object like List<SelectItem> selectItemsCollection with all those objects you want to be in  the select. The object SelectItem coud have, for example, two properties, like String title and String value where you store the label and the value.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Collection<?>` with some object inside. You can create your own object or use `SelectItem.class`

and then,

```
<form:select multiple="true" path="harmonic">
  <form:options items="${selectMultiple}" itemValue="value" itemLabel="name"/>
</form:select>
```

Comment: Just to finish clarifying, could I use an integer collection? The select is to allow the user to select from a range of integers.

Comment: Yes you can. need to modify a little. Just remove itemvalue and itemlabel from my solution

Answer (score 1):

Use a list of elements

```
public class HarmonicForm{

    private Listy<Harmonic> harmonic;

}

public class Harmonic{
    //Be sure to implement equals and hashcode 
}
```

You can find a similar case here [Spring select multiple tag and binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10778428/spring-select-multiple-tag-and-binding)